# webpack +angular material2 template parser error

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material

I try to use the webpack to pack the project.
But When I add the angular material2. there will some error message on the console.
[image]

the way I use material.

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoginModule,
        AdminModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule,
        MaterialModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService,
        LoggerService,
        AuthGuardService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

the component file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: './angularMaterial.html',
  styleUrls: ['./angularMaterial.css'],
})
export class AngularMaterialComponent {
  favoriteSeason: string;

  seasons = [
    'Winter',
    'Spring',
    'Summer',
    'Autumn',
  ];
}
```

the html file:

```
<md-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
    <md-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
        {{season}}
    </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
<div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
```

the css file:

```
.example-radio-group {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.example-radio-button {
    margin: 5px;
}

.example-selected-value {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
```

I use the deom from [angular material-radio demo](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio)

Comment: In Html the radio button 'value' is not assigning. So assign the *ngFor to  'md-radio-group' tag

Comment: You can the theming guide in angular material https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 1):

While Importing Material Module you need to import forRoot. For example you need to declare it as

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoginModule,
        AdminModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule,
        MaterialModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

Comment: I  use  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2" which don't use the forRoot()

Comment: In Style.css have u declared the configuration like md-core change it to mat-core

Comment: No,I haven't do that

Comment: Refer the link angular/material theming: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md

Comment: maybe the "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2" is unstable. There have a lots of questions.

Comment: Create one scss file and import the theming configuration in your application and include in app.component.ts file and add in styleUrls:[yourstyle.scss]